# Socket IO and Express Cross origin error or 404 not found error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I am getting cross origin headers error despite running cors library, or simply a 404 not found while polling in the console.

The project structure looks like this

[image]

My goal is to have the little chat widget on every view. I will include this to the other views as EJS partial.

I am not sure what I going wrong I have tried to run Express on port 5000 and Socket IO on 8080 or 3000, all different combinations have not yielded anything good.

APP.JS looks like this

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const config = require("config");
const flash = require('express-flash');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const Mailgen = require("mailgen");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const appController = require("./controllers/appController");
const isAuth = require("./middleware/is-auth");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const mongoURI = config.get("mongoURI");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var cors = require('cors')     // This should help, but does nothing
const app = express();       
const http = require('http').Server(app);      // I suspect the mistake is in these lines
const io = require('socket.io')(http,
{
cors: {
origin: "http://localhost:5000",              // Does nothing
credentials: true
}})

connectDB();

const store = new MongoDBStore({
uri: mongoURI,
collection: "mySessions",
}); 
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}))                       // Also seems not to be working

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));




//Middleware and Routes



io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log("hello")         // never happened
socket.on('username', function(username) {
console.log("hello")            // never happened

  socket.username = username;
  io.emit('is_online', ' <i>' + socket.username + ' join the chat..</i>');
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(username) {
  io.emit('is_online', ' <i>' + socket.username + ' left the chat..</i>');
  })

  socket.on('chat_message', function(message) {
  io.emit('chat_message', '<strong>' + socket.username + '</strong>: ' + message);
  });

  });

  app.listen(5000, console.log("App Running on http://localhost:5000"));
```

And the front end partial EJS looks like this

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="/" method="POST" id="chatForm">
<input id="txt" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on" oninput="isTyping()" placeholder="type your message 
 here..." /><button>Send</button>
</form>
```

The rest of the front end page looks like this

```
  <head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style> etcetc


<%- include ('./partialChatWidget.ejs') %>
```

And the JS

```
<Script> 
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000', { transport : ['websocket'] } );

$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    socket.emit('chat_message', $('#txt').val());
    $('#txt').val('');
    return false;
});

socket.on('chat_message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(msg));
});

socket.on('is_online', function(username) {
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(username));
});

var username = prompt('Please tell me your name');
socket.emit('username', username);
</script>
```

So what is going wrong here, do I need 2 servers on different ports or 2 instances, I always thought socket IO borrows the http server , not the express instance.

Thanks for helping me out. I might add I get the cross origin errors when I try to run on 2 different ports. Else I get 404 not found in the console. The page and the partial and the initial JS(Jquery) run.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of back and forth....

Just make sure to load the front end link for socket IO right in the head section asap.

And do include this part on the front end

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000', { transport : ['websocket'] } );
```

Definitely include this on the server side, this cant hurt, unless you want to block some pages from CORS access

```
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}))
```

The next 2 steps made it all work.

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http,
{
cors: {
origin: "http://localhost:5000 {this is the port of your back end app, not for the socket IO port }",
credentials: true
}})
```

And finally, indeed, 2 servers.

```
const server = http.listen(8080, function() {
console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
app.listen(5000, console.log("App Running on http://localhost:5000"));
```

Took me a while, but now everything is clear once and for all(I hope)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use((req,res, next)=>{
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"http://localhost:3000");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',"*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
```

});

> use this code
> and install the older socket.io version 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
`const server = app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('a user connected');
});`
```